# Why would a Drupal form not be cached in cache_form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

My form, lets call it `organize_issue`, is a form in a custom module being called from the menu using the page callback `drupal_get_form` function. The form works perfectly well.

I'm trying to implement some AHAH type functionality now, and need to get the page from cache using `form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state)` but, oddly enough, my form isn't being cached. Ever. Other forms on the site are, just not this one. As I said the form works fine, and submits and validates and whatnot... it just never caches. Is their something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function that builds the form you should have a value setting the form to cache...

Should look some thing like `'#cache' => TRUE`, if you don't see it that might be why your form isn't caching...you should be building your form on a way that the array of the form sets it to cache:

```
<?php
  function _organize_issue_form($node) {
    global $user;

 $form = array(
   '#theme' => 'organize_issue',
   '#cache' => TRUE,
 );
?>
```

HTH